# Type of Collector returned by Collectors.toList()

Tags: java, java-8

I am quite puzzled about the Collectors.toList() and Collectors.toSet() static methods. These two methods do not take in any parameters. So how do they know what types of Collector to return?

For example, if we have this line:

```
Collectors.toList();
```

The returned Collector is `Collector<Object,?,List<Object>>`.

If we have this line:

```
Collector<Integer,?,List<Integer>> c = Collectors.toList();
```

Then Collectors.toList() will return a `Collector<Integer,?,List<Integer>>`. Without taking in any input parameters, how does the toList() method know that it needs to return a `Collector<Integer,?,List<Integer>>`?

Perhaps a sample codes of how toList() is written would be helpful in my understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#Collectors.toList%28%29

Answer (score 5):

This feature is introduced as [target type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types) in generic type inference.

> The Java compiler takes advantage of **target typing** to infer the **type parameters** of a generic method invocation. The target type of an expression is the data type that the Java compiler expects depending on where the expression appears.

For example:

```
//         v--- the generic parameter `T` is inferred by the target type 
Collector<Integer,?,List<Integer>> c = Collectors.toList();

//         v--- the unbounded type parameter is extends `Object`
Collectors.toList();
```

Comment: Would you be able to show some codes on how toList() is implemented?

Comment: @user3573403 type inference is implemented by java compiler rather than java source code. if you change the code to `Collector<Integer,?,List<String>> c = Collectors.toList();` you found the code can't be compiled, since the `toList()` method only contains single type parameter `T`.

Comment: @user3573403 hi, there is a fully example in [target type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types). and the target type expression for generic invocation is fully supported in java8.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you wanted to collect a list of even integers into another list.

You can write this:

```
// assume that integerList contains ints between 1 and 20
List<Integer> evenInts = integerList.stream().filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`collect` is [a terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/stream/Collectors.html) in the stream, and it is expected to return a type bound by `R`, which in this case, translates to `List<Integer>`.  This is how it's able to appropriately collect your elements in.

You're encouraged here to [peruse more information about `Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html), as it's part of the newer Java 8 Stream API and can be a bit curious to get into once you start.

Comment: You are not answering my question. I do know how to use Collectors.toList() and have in fact written my own collector.

Comment: @user3573403 If you keep reading, you'll observe that I do address your specific question.  The answer is due to how types are bound, and `R` is the type being used as the return value.