# Filter Custom Objects in Array list or List

Tags: android, list, arraylist, filter

I have 50 Custom Class(class name : Student) objects in array List .

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String parent;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(String parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

I want to filter the students array list whose age is 20  and store it into another array list.

Note :

I have tried with for loop. its working fine. But I want to know Is there any fastest way other than looping array list to filter student age.

I have some experience in iOS. In iOS, NSPredicate is there to filter student age from NSArray. I just started learning android since last month. I am not getting any answer other than looping array list over internet to achieve the same.

Comment: *any fastest way other than looping array list* ... obviously with custom predicate there is no way of filtering without iterating all elements

Answer (score 2):

You can use [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) library to get [Java 8 stream](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) similar functions:

```
List<Student> filteredList = StreamSupport
            .stream(yourInputStudentList)
            .filter(item -> item.getAge() == "20")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To do so, you need add update your gradle file like below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0' // Add this         
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW: the age should not be a string, but a int? Off topic though.

Comment: It says "Can not resolve method 'stream(java.util.List<Student>)'.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704901/type-of-collector-returned-by-collectors-tolist

Answer (score 1):

You use Lightweight-Stream-API:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.2'
}
```

then using:

```
    import com.annimon.stream.Stream;
    import com.annimon.stream.function.Predicate;
    import com.annimon.stream.Collector;

..............

List<Student> filteredList = Stream.of(yourInputStudentList).filter(new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Student item) {
                return item.getAge().equals("20");
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Lamda:

```
    import com.annimon.stream.Stream;
    import com.annimon.stream.function.Predicate;

..............

List<Student> filteredList = Stream.of(yourInputStudentList).filter(item-> item.getAge().equals("20")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi brother. I am getting this error "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.stream.Collectors$CollectorImpl cannot be cast to com.annimon.stream.Collector". Whe I use your first option.

Comment: You import com.annimon.sream.Collector please

Comment: remove import  java.util.stream.Collectors then add import com.annimon.stream.Collector.